# typescript - Calling a method from Extended Class returns <empty string>

Tags: typescript

### Issue

I'm following a tutorial and have run aground. Calling the method 'bark()' in the ShelterDog class returns *`<empty string>`* in the browser console instead of the expected `"WOOF WOOF!!!"`

### Code

```
// Dog.ts
export default class Dog {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public breed: string,
        public age: number
    ) {}
    bark():void {
        console.log("WOOF WOOF!!!");
    }
}
```

```
// ShelterDog.ts

import Dog from "./Dog.js";

export default class ShelterDog extends Dog {
    constructor(
        name: string,
        breed: string,
        age: number,
        public shelter: string
    ) {
        super(name, breed, age);
        this.shelter = shelter
    }
}
```

```
// index.ts

import Dog from "./Dog.js"
import ShelterDog from "./ShelterDog.js"

const elton = new Dog("Elton", "Aussie", 0.5)
elton.bark()

const benton = new ShelterDog("Benton","Madman",99,"Chaos Refuge")
benton.bark()
```

Comment: this works for me ! try to console.log(benton) after declaration

Comment: That's odd... it works but if I take the console.log away the method is only called once. If I change the method to run `console.log(\`${this.name} says: WOOF WOOF!!!\`);` then it calls twice.

Answer (score 0):

This code was working as expected. I simply overlooked the fact that the Firefox browser console groups repeated logs.

[image: Grouped Log Repeat]

Note: I believe There is also apparently some issue with the option to disable this functionality currently.

Comment: OMG hhh in your console there is a setting icon. click on it then uncheck grouped console message if you want

Comment: I tried that but still not separating them xD weird